# LINQ - nested where clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a problem with a project. I’m trying to get a list of companies, but only filter those companies that are located in “Stockholm”.

Table structure

```
**Company**:
CompanyID
CompanyName
etc…

**CompanyAddressDetails** (relation table):
Company_CompanyID
CorrespondingAddress_AddressID

**CorrespondingAddress**:
AddressID
StreetName
City
etc…
```

Now what I first do is a query:

```
var companyModel = from c in db.Company select c;
```

Which gets the full list of companies and having their Corresponding Addresses (which can be multiple), so the results looks like this:

[image]

So my question is: how can I filter depending on what one of the nestled elements under CorrespondingAddress is? City for example?

So far I tried

```
companyModel = companyModel.Where(s => s.CorrespondingAddress.Where(x => x.City.Equals("Stockholm")));
companyModel = companyModel.Where(s => s.CorrespondingAddress.ToList().First().Address.Equals("Stockholm"));
```

But none of them works. Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
companyModel = companyModel
               .Where(s => s.CorrespondingAddress
                     .Any(x => x.City.Equals("Stockholm")));
```

Comment: I didn't find this elsewhere, so thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Why second `where` in OP's first try is not working?

Comment: @ninbit cause it tests only if the "first" corresponding address of the company (you don't even know in which order the correponding adresses are tested) is in Stockholm. And what we want is "at least one" corresponding address, not "first". For example, if a company has an address in London, and another one in Stockholm, the OP's query may not return the company, while the one with "Any" will.

Answer (score 8):

Try Any()

```
companyModel = companyModel.Where(s => s.CorrespondingAddress.Any(x => x.City.Equals("Stockholm")));
```